# Dynamically renaming files using batch with no fixed position for string

Tags: timestamp, batch-rename

I have a batch of files needing dynamic fie name change. e.g. file name

```
abc_def_ghi_20180609123211.txt
```

There are 2 tasks at hand

1. I need to remove the timestamp and the underscore along with the
   timestamp so the file name becomes `abc_def_ghi.txt`
2. For now the timestamp is at 3rd underscore as in the example  `abc_def_ghi_20180609123211.txt`. But in future it may not be. Regardless, timestamp will always be after the last underscore (in the future the last underscore may still be 3rd or be at 4th or 5th etc .. positions)..

I am not too familiar with batch files. I tried

```
for /F %%i in ('dir /b *.txt') do echo mv %%i %%i_1

DIR nofile || (PAUSE && EXIT /B 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

That is easily done with a PowerShell one liner incorporating a RegEx matching the 14 digits of the timestamp at the end of the basename (name without extension)

```
ls *_*_*.txt|? BaseName -match '(_\d{14})$'|REN -NewName {$_.Name -replace $Matches[1]} -Whatif
```

If the output looks OK, remove the trailing `-WhatIf`

The same code withous aliases:

```
Get-ChildItem *_*_*.txt|Where-Object BaseName -match '(_\d{14})$'|
    Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace $Matches[1]} -Whatif
```

Comment: I would think it might be better to use non aliased commands no? Also, the `.*` in your regex is redundant.